# Loop between two large numbers in few minutes

Tags: java

I want to loop from `0.900000000000000000000000000000` to `0.999999999999999999999999999999` (**30 digit after decimal**) with step of `0.000000000000000000000000000001` . I used for loop and it takes hours of time. Can it be done in few minutes ?

Comment: that´s like 1 Nonillion iterations, for sure it does take time.

Comment: Can you show the code ? Depending on what you do in the loop, taking hours is not really surprising...

Comment: `totalTime = numberOfIterations * timeOfIteration`. Only value that you can change here is time of single iteration to complete. shorten that and you get shorter total time.

Comment: Could you please add an explanation why such a strange loop is necessary?

Comment: That is about 10^30 different values to loop through. According to IPS listings on wikipedia, an Intel Core i7 Processor can do about 10^11 instructions per second. That means, even if we can do each loop iteration with only one processor instruction (completely unreasonable assumption), it will take ~10^19 seconds. That is ~10^12 years (approx a billion years). So what you're asking for is completely unreasonable no matter what programming language you use.

Comment: Also, what kind of data type are you using for the variable? A java `double` is 64 bit and can represent 10^18 different values, and only a fraction of these are between `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 5):

Lets just assume your loop will execute 10 billion times per second. It would still take ~10^19 seconds for your program to terminate. According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%5E19%20seconds%20in%20days), thats like 23 times the age of our universe.
So no, you cannot finish in just a few minutes.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, even in fews seconds :
http://www.dwavesys.com/quantum-computing

Else : 
Do not display / print something

Why would you do that ?

Use a better computer ?

Do not use Java ?

Comment: Can you suggest a language that iterates faster than Java?

Comment: @SleimanJneidi  It's depend on what is inside the loop, but I guess it will not be an very important diff by loop, but with so many loop it can make an important difference.